# how to check the values in same elseif statement in C#

Tags: c#

I want to check the when Category is 'Bank' then Remark should either be 'In queue'  or blank value  then it should exit from else if condition if both the statements are false display the console message-

```
else if (Category == "Bank" && (Remark != "In queue" || Remark != ""){
      Console.WriteLine("When Category is 'Bank' then Remark Should be In queue ");
}
```

But in above code one statements is false and one true so it is displaying the console message.It should check either of one condition and anyone statement is true exit from the elseif statement.
Please help me on same.

Comment: your code is not VB.NET

Comment: oops...sorry...It is in C#.net

Comment: An empty string (Remark != "") is not the same thing as null. Also you mention exiting the else if statement block, but if your conditions are not met then it never goes in and you never have to exit it. Also if else statements don't have an exit ability; things like while, case, foreach do.

Comment: your check is good, except you have made a mistake and missed single **)** after your else if condition. Just put it before the first curly bracket **{**

Also, if there is a **if** or **else if** statement that is truthful, before this one, it might be the case that this condition is never evaluated, because the  condition before this one is satisfied first.

Comment: Why not use an Enum here? Clean and Enum.Parse(typeof(Remark)) before heading into your checks. It's hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as below

```
 if (Category == "Bank" && !(Remark == "" || Remark == "In queue" ))
{
    Console.WriteLine("When Category is 'Bank' then Remark Should be In queue ");
}
```

Comment: @Damith-I want to check the condition for null values as well

Comment: if Remark  is null then `Remark <> "In queue"` is true then it display the message, you don't need another condition to check null

Answer (score 0):

else if (Category == "Bank" and  (Remark <> "In queue" or Remark <> ""))
 Console.WriteLine("When Category is 'Bank' then Remark Should be In queue ")

Answer (score 0):

Your Remark checks will always come back true.

Having two != checks against a string with an || means that anything will make either side validate as true. **Remark** could be a null, or string.Empty or "In queue", it does not matter because one will always be satisfied.